# How to efficiently replace the repetitive sequence?

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

The problem is how to determine the repetitive sequences and replace the part with consecutive sequences
For example:
`A={{1,3,4},{2,3,5},{1,6}}`
Then, detect there are the repetitive case for 1 and 3 and become
`A={{1,4,6},{3,5,7},{2,8}}`

**Updates**

Q1:How can I assign the repetitive sequences in lists(transpose tableform) with the rules:

-Highest level & no blocked on the top will be assigned lower number.

-High level with similar repetition will follow later.

-The one underneath the other number will be much later.
[image]
For example:Input

```
A={{2,1},{2,2},{1,2},{1},{2,1,1}};
Print[Rotate[
  Grid[Map[Rotate[#, -90 Degree] &, A, {-1}], Frame -> All], 
  90 Degree]]
```

[image]

And implement the rules to get the output:

[image]

Q2:How can I generate all the possible list outcomes without the rules when the lists have repetitive cases?

Comment: This is usually called 'standardization' in combinatorics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[addIndices, addOrderings, standardize]
```

Append to each entry of the input list its index and the length of its parent sublist:

```
addIndices[a_] := {#, #4, {#2, #3}} & @@@ Join @@ 
    (Flatten /@ Thread[{#, Length @ #}] & /@ MapIndexed[List, a, {2}]);
```

Use `SortBy[{First, f2, f3,...}]` to sort the annotated list using sorting functions `f2`, `f3`,..., that represent your *rules*, and add the orderings obtained to the annotated list.

In the implementation below, the sorting functions `#[[2]] - #[[3, 2]] &`  and `-#[[2]] &` capture your rules:

```
addOrderings = MapIndexed[{#[[1]], #2[[1]], #[[3]]} &]@ 
    SortBy[{First, #[[2]] - #[[3, 2]] &, -#[[2]] &}]@# &;
```

Compose the `addOrderings` with `addIndices`:

```
standardize = addOrderings @* addIndices;
```

to generate a list of triples `{a, number_assigned_to_a, {row, column}}`.

**Example:**

```
standardize[A2]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 1, {5, 3}},
>   {1, 2, {1, 2}}, 
>   {1, 3, {4, 1}},
>   {1, 4, {5, 2}}, 
>   {1, 5, {3, 1}},
>   {2, 6, {2, 2}},
>   {2, 7, {3, 2}}, 
>   {2, 8, {1, 1}},
>   {2, 9, {2, 1}}, 
>   {2, 10, {5, 1}}}
> ```

```
DeleteCases[0] /@ Normal[SparseArray[#3 -> #2 & @@@ standardize[A2]]]
```

> ```
>  {{8, 2}, {9, 6}, {5, 7}, {3}, {10, 4, 1}}
> ```

```
SparseArray[Reverse@#3 -> # & @@@ standardize[A2]] // Reverse // 
 Grid[Normal[#] /. 0 -> "", Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

```
SparseArray[Reverse@#3 -> #2 & @@@ standardize[A2]] // Reverse // 
  Grid[Normal[#] /. 0 -> "", Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
ClearAll[f]
f = TakeList[Ordering@Ordering@Flatten@#, Length /@ #] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
A1 = {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 5}, {1, 6}};

f @ A1
```

> ```
>  {{1, 4, 6}, {3, 5, 7}, {2, 8}}
> ```

```
A2 = {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}, {1}, {2, 1, 1}};

f @ A2
```

> ```
> {{6, 1}, {7, 8}, {2, 9}, {3}, {10, 4, 5}}
> ```

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[pad]
pad = Reverse[Transpose[PadRight[#, Automatic, ""]]] &;

pad @ A2 // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

If we use `f`  on  `pad @ A` non-numeric entries will be assigned numbers greater than `Length@Flatten@A`, Removing non-numeric elements from `f @ pad @ A` gives the desired result:

```
f[pad @ A2] /. x_ /; x > Length[Flatten @ A2] -> "" // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[g]
g[a_] := Select[# <= Length @ Flatten @ a &] /@ Transpose @ Reverse @ f @ pad @ a

g @ A2
```

> ```
> {{8, 2}, {9, 6}, {4, 7}, {5}, {10, 3, 1}}
> ```

Comment: If your version of Mathematica does not have `TakeList` then try `TakeList = If[#2 == {}, #1, Prepend[#0[Drop[#1, First@#2], Rest@#2], Take[#1, First@#2]]] &;`

Comment: How can I efficiently assign the sequence for repeated cases(like randomly assigned or specific method), for example when there are 4 or even more number of no. 1 in the list, so that when I retrieve each number according to the sequences will be more effective by reducing the blocks on each targeted no. in tableform-transpose.

Comment: @tjx6499, the method should work for any number of repetitions. If you have an example where the method fails, please update your question with the example input and desired output.

Comment: @kglr, how can I get the outcome in list form={{8,2},{9,6},{4,7},{5},{10,3,1}}?

Comment: @kglr, it is possible to get the same desired result with rules that I stated in my question={{8, 2}, {9, 6}, {5, 7}, {3}, {10, 4, 1}}?

Comment: @tjx6499, I am afraid i don't understand _"The one underneath the other number will be much later" and how exactly you got `{{8, 2}, {9, 6}, {5, 7}, {3}, {10, 4, 1}}`. If it is not too much trouble, can you add an explanation of the steps you followed to get from `{{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {1, 2}, {1}, {2, 1, 1}}`  to  `{{8, 2}, {9, 6}, {5, 7}, {3}, {10, 4, 1}}`?

Comment: @kglr, I drew sth to add the explanation on the repetitive cases for "1", pls see my update in the question.

Comment: Thank you @tjx6499.

Comment: @tjx6499, please see the update.

Comment: Thank you very much @kglr.